# What's wrong with my Java code about HashMap?

Tags: java

This is the error notification:

> Library.java:13: error: cannot find symbol
>         for (String book : library.KeySet()) {
>                                   ^   symbol:   method KeySet()   location: variable library of type HashMap 1 error

And this is the code:

```
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Library{
  public Library(){

  }

  public void getFinishedBooks (HashMap<String, Boolean> library){ 
    if(library.size() < 1){
      System.out.println("Bye");   
    }
    else {
      for (String book : library.KeySet()) {
        if (library.get(book) == true) {
          System.out.println(book);
        }
      }
    }

  }

      public static void main(String[] args) {
      HashMap<String,Boolean> myBooks=new HashMap<String, Boolean>();

      myBooks.put("Road Down The Funnel",true);
      myBooks.put("Rat: A Biology",false);
      myBooks.put("TimeIn",true);
      myBooks.put("3D Food Printing",false);


      Library myLibrary = new Library();
      myLibrary.getFinishedBooks(myBooks);


    }
}
```

I would like to know what's wrong with this piece of code? especially line 13? Thanks.

Comment: It's `keySet` isn't it? Case matters.

Comment: Change `String book : library.KeySet()` to `String book : library.keySet()`. Take care of the case. Java method names usually use cameCase convention

Comment: Use an IDE like NetBeans and you wouldn't have problems like this.

Comment: Don't you use IDE in this days? keySet() k is lowercase. Just a typo mistake..

Comment: understood, many thanks. btw I am following online tutorial, so I finish it on online platform, next time I will done it in IDE first. thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a typo, use `keySet()` instead of `KeySet()`

```
 for (String book : library.keySet()) { }
```